# Python pandas get rows from left table and from right table missing in left table

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I have left and right table and I need to merge FileStamp values from both in this manner: take all values from left table and from right table missing in left table, join it by 'date':

```
import pandas as pd
left = pd.DataFrame({'FileStamp': ['T101', 'T102', 'T103', 'T104'], 'date': [20180101, 20180102, 20180103, 20180104]})
right = pd.DataFrame({'FileStamp': ['T501', 'T502'], 'date': [20180104, 20180105]})
```

Something like

```
result = pd.merge(left, right, how='outer', on='date')
```

but 'outer' is not good idea.

Desired output should look like

```
     FileStamp_x      date      FileStamp_y
0        T101       20180101         NaN
1        T102       20180102         NaN
2        T103       20180103         NaN
3        T104       20180104         NaN
4         NaN       20180105        T502
```

Is there any simple way how to achieve desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use filtering by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) before `merge`:

```
r = right[~right['date'].isin(left['date'])]
print (r)
  FileStamp      date
1      T502  20180105

result = pd.merge(left, r, how='outer', on='date')
print (result)
  FileStamp_x      date FileStamp_y
0        T101  20180101         NaN
1        T102  20180102         NaN
2        T103  20180103         NaN
3        T104  20180104         NaN
4         NaN  20180105        T502
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the values after the `merge`:

```
result = pd.merge(left, right, how='outer', on='date')
result['FileStamp_y'] = np.where(result['FileStamp_x'].isnull(), result['FileStamp_y'], np.nan)
```

Result:

```
    FileStamp_x     date  FileStamp_y
0          T101 20180101          NaN
1          T102 20180102          NaN
2          T103 20180103          NaN
3          T104 20180104          NaN
4           NaN 20180105         T502
```